How to write a unit test to determine if an operation takes about linear time?
I am writing unit tests in JUnit 5 for a Java codebase, though I'm happy to take examples in any language.
I have the ability to count the exact number of times certain operations occur. For the sake of an easy example, let's say the number of comparisons made during a sort.
I'd like to write a unit test that asserts the number of operations performed is in one of four Big Oh complexity classes: constant, linear, nlogn, or quadratic.
So I can, for example, build a list of size 1, sort it, and record the number of operations. Then do the same for a list of size 2, then size 3, etc. The problem is that the relationship between these numbers of comparisons may not be exactly constant, linear, etc. but I want to know which of the four classes they are most like.
What is a good way to detect, while allowing for some error and variation, which of those four classes is the best fit for my sequence of numbers? Ideally, this method would account for amortization.
As an example of amortization, say I want to show that adding an element to an array list takes constant time. The policy for the list is that the array starts at size 5 and doubles each time it fills up. I insert 1 element, then record the number of operations (say memory writes). Insert another element, record the number of operations, and so on for n elements. The number of operations will look something like this:
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1...

The 6 occurs when the new array is allocated. This sequence is not exactly constant, but constant is the best fit of the four classes.
EDIT: The best solution I have so far is to find a best fit for an equation of the form:

And then check the constants. If a, b, and c are all close to 0, then the function is constant. If a and b are close to 0, then the function is linear. If a is close to 0, the function is log linear. Otherwise, it is quadratic.
I know this is not a general theoretical solution to the problem in a mathematical sense, but I think this will catch the most common operations for basic data structures and algorithms (lists, binary trees, sorting, minimum spanning trees, etc.).

I would be very surprised (and intrigued) if this were possible.

I don't need it to be perfect. I just need to know when a sequence that I expected to be more or less constant is actually more or less linear. Or when a sequence I expected to be more or less linear ended up being more or less quadratic.

I would be very surprised (and intrigued) if even that were possible.

First let's start with the boring answer: whether a function belongs in a given complexity class is a purely mathematical concept that cannot be tested for experimentally. Sure you could run the algorithm for n = 100, 200, and 300, and then compare the results somehow, but there is no guarantee that you will get anything interesting out of that.
The more interesting thing to realize is that complexity classes are typically not something your users care about. What they care about is whether the operations they perform take a long time or not. So rather than trying to test for complexity classes, I would rather suggest the following: write a test at the upper limit of how your function is meant to be used (no need to test for n = 1000000 if in practice it never goes above 100) and assert that the time/number of operations it took is under a reasonable upper limit.
So maybe if n is usually under 100, you can test with n = 200, and make sure it performs less than 500 operations (for a linear algorithm). If someone manages to change the algorithm to a quadratic one, that should surely catch it. And if it doesn't, that means the quadratic algorithm isn't actually much worse, so it doesn't matter.
It will be way easier to write such a test, and the test will also be closer to what you actually want to test.

This would be a good answer for most cases, but in this case my users are the students in a Data Structures class, and we do actually care about the complexity class.

Even then, it still feels like the best option to me. Otherwise nothing would prevent a student to first perform a billion useless operations, just to make your test believe that the complexity of their algorithm is O(1) (as it always takes around a billion operations no matter the input).

Sure. I'm not looking for a perfect solution that has no vulnerabilities. These unit tests are meant to help students notice problems before they turn in their projects for a grade.

This is the correct answer—I think the simplest solution is to change one's criteria to include nonfunctional timing requirements, eg problem size 1000 items completes in under 0.1s.
